# is there an equivalent to [[SomeClass new] autorelease] in objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I know that I could implement as a category on NSObject, but is there an existing method for:

```
+(id)auto
{
    return [[self new]autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many classes provide convenience methods to do just that:

```
+ (id)string
```

is a method of `NSString`, for example.

Comment: yeah, they do. Seems like they all could, just like new is alloc/init something in NSObject could be alloc/init/autorelease.

Comment: well not all... NSManagedObject for instance wouldn't work any better than a naked alloc/init.